# How to differentiate between standard-inputs (via pipe and via prompt) in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, stdin, prompt

My goal: piping standard input from `echo` to a node file **and** asking for more input via a prompt. But I need to know which input is from the piping and which one is from the prompt.

The node file **x.js** looks like this:

```js
const readline = require("readline");

let rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

rl.question("yes or no? (y/n)", answer => {
    console.log("-" + answer + "-");
    rl.close();
});
```

This one works (A prompt is shown, I enter "hello" and it is written to the console):

`> node x.js
-hello-`

But this does not work (There is no prompt. The piped string is just written to the console.):

`> echo "abcdefgh" | node x.js
-abcdefgh-`

How can I differentiate between those 2 kinds of standard input?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your problem is worse than you think - the problem is not differentiating between the piped and keyboard input, it's being able to accept both in the first place.

When you pipe data, you're basically saying "**THIS is my input**" - the application can no longer capture keyboard input, and in fact stdin is closed immediately after the piped data is read.

Are you completely boned? Well, it depends what you want to do. As per your example, if you want to make the user confirm that something is OK before accepting it, you could use command-line arguments:

```
var stdin = process.stdin;

if (stdin.setRawMode)
{
        // No data is being piped, so fall back to your existing code
        const readline = require("readline");

        let rl = readline.createInterface({
            input: process.stdin,
            output: process.stdout
        });

        rl.question("yes or no? (y/n)", answer =>
        {
            console.log("-" + answer + "-");
            rl.close();
        });
}
else
{
        // resume stdin in the parent process (node app won't quit all by itself

        stdin.resume();

        // on any data into stdin
        let receivedData = '';
        stdin.on('data', (data) => {
                receivedData += data;
        });
        stdin.on('end', () => {
                // Input will have a \n appended
                receivedData = receivedData.slice(0, -1);

                console.log('I received "' + receivedData + '".');
                const args = process.argv.slice(2);
                for(const arg of args)
                {
                        if (arg.toLowerCase() === '--accept')
                        {
                                console.log('Accepted the input!');
                                return;
                        }
                }
                console.log('Is this OK? If so, pass --accept as a parameter');
        });
}
```

And it works like this:

```
~ # echo "abcdefhiy" | node input.js

I received "abcdefhiy".
Is this OK? If so, pass --accept as a parameter

~ # echo "abcdefhiy" | node input.js --accept

I received "abcdefhiy".
Accepted the input!
```

Comment: Thanks. But the thing is: The command is not actually as simple as `echo "abcdefhiy" | node input.js --accept`. It's more like `node thisruns15minutes.js | node input.js`. So I do not want the user to run the whole thing again with the additional parameter..

Comment: Then the answer, i'm afraid, is simply "You can't do that". If you choose to pipe input into stdin, you can't also accept keyboard input.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer given by Tom Mettam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59359710/1563507) is not quite  right.

It is true that `process.stdin` is occupied by the pipe input, meaning that you cannot also then use it for keyboard input.

But that doesn't mean you can't use keyboard input at all. You can use the underlying TTY readStream that `process.stdin` relies on.

The easiest way I've found to do this is by using the Node package [ttys](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ttys), which is very simple but saves me having to write the same code again.

I think you would use `tty.stdin` and `tty.stdout` as the arguments for your `readline` interface. You could then still use process arguments to access what was piped in.

I just posted [an answer to my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61530260/1563507) on a very similar problem, which you might find useful to read for implementation purposes.